# AngularJS - How to access directly a $scope's row/value from the controller

Tags: angularjs, controller, scope

I'm newbie in AngularJS but am very eager to master it, so please forget my ignorance. I have two problems making a basic blog:

**Problem #1:** I have a controller that uses $http and receives a JSON perfectly.

This is the app.js:

```
angular.module('blogApp', []).config(['$routeProvider',
function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.when('/home', {
    templateUrl : 'home.html'
}).when('/post/:postId', {
    templateUrl : 'post.html',
    controller : postCtrl
}).otherwise({
    redirectTo : '/home'
});
}]);
```

This is the controller.js:

```
function postCtrl($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
$http.get('post.php?id=' + $routeParams.postId).success(function(data) {
    $scope.post = data;
});

$scope.description = $scope.post.meta_description;  /*I can't access this value*/
```

}

And this is the JSON that $scope.post receives when #/post/123 is used:

```
[
    {
        'id':'123',
        'title':'title of the post',
        'date':'2013-06-14',
        'content':'This is the content of the post.<br>She had a yellow house.',
        'meta_description':'description of my first post.'
    }
]
```

The problem is that in the controller.js, I can't access $scope.post.meta_description. Also I have tried with $scope.post[0].meta_description, with data.post.meta_description and with data.post[0].meta_description without a positive result.

---

**Problem #2:** In post.html, I have this code

```
<div>
    <h1>{{post[0].title}}</h1>
    <h2>Published on {{post[0].date}}</h2>
    {{post[0].content}}
</div>
```

I practiced the full AngularJS' tutorial, and should be using {{post.title}} but AngularJS doesn't print anything. To solve it, I use {{post[0].title}}. Why happens this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you would need to do something like

ng-repeat post in posts for your problem 2.

For problem 1, I think you need to make the actual http call.

$scope.post = // your function call to get the data.

Comment: for problem #2: exactly, in that way, it works but I don't understand why in http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_08, they load a JSON with one record, and access to a field using phone.additionalFeatures without using ng-repeat.

Why didn't they use phone[0].additionalFeatures?

Comment: phone.additionalFeatures is a jsonObject ( not a jsonArray) , while in your case you have an Array. An Array can be looped through using ng-repeat

Comment: Ok, now I understand the difference between JSONObject and JSONArray. The problem #2 is solved. Thank you.

Comment: But still I don't understand how to get data.meta_description from outside of the $http.get function.

Comment: Ok, I think you're talking about using $resource, like in http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_11

Comment: Ready, I found a better way. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First one

```
$scope.description = $scope.post[0].meta_description;
```

Please, pay attention to fact that server returns `Array` with single item which type is `Hash`.

I guess it's clue to your trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Conclusions:
For **problem #2**. There a two types of JSON.

a)**JSONObject** like this single row:

```
{
    'id':'123',
    'title':'my house'
}
```

b)**JSONArray** like this single row:

```
[
    {
       'id':'123',
        'title':'my house'
    }
]
```

Do you see the brackets? Or like this other JSONArray:

```
[
    {
       'id':'123',
        'title':'my house'
    },
    {
       'id':'124',
       'title':'my car'
    }
]
```

With JSONObjects, you must use {{post.title}} in the template.

```
<div>
    {{post.title}}
</div>
```

{{post[0].title}} shall give you an error because data isn't an array. It doesn't use brackets.

And with JSONArrays (with one or more rows), you can use ng-repeat in the template, like:

```
<div ng-repeat="post in post">
    {{post.title}}
</div>
```

Or, also you can access directly a specific row:

```
<div>
    {{post[0].title}}
    <br>
    {{post[1].title}}
</div>
```

---

For **problem #1**, you could use something like explained here:

[Step #11 in AngularJS' tutorial ($resource)](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_11)

But, I found easier to do a single change; this is my previous code:

```
function postCtrl($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
    $http.get('post.php?id=' + $routeParams.postId).success(function(data) {
        $scope.post = data;
    });

    $scope.description = $scope.post.meta_description;  /*I can't access this value*/
}
```

The problem is $scope.post only exists inside the function inside $http.get; it's like a private variable that can't be access from outside of the function.

So an easier solution than to use $resource, was to move $scope.description inside $http.get.

```
function postCtrl($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
    $http.get('post.php?id=' + $routeParams.postId).success(function(data) {
        $scope.post = data;
        $scope.description = data.meta_description;
    });
}
```